# Recycle a bitmap and use it later?

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

Is there any way that I can recycle a bitmap and use it again later. When I recycle my bitmaps i can't use it later it gives me `NullPointerException`  so is there any way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: can you paste your code so that we get clear picture of whats happening

Answer (score 2):

If you are recycling bitmaps it means you are removing them from the memory. So after they are not in the memory if you want to use them again you must load them once again.

So hold bitmaps in memory if you have enough memory space, and you want to reuse it. But if you will remove them from memory the only way is to reload them back once again.